# How to config Environment for Image bitbucket pipeline

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I config bitbucket pipeline using mysql image, but I don't know how to set MySQL password. As docker document, it's an environment variable (MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORK), but I don't know to config in pipeline file. Please help me.

This is my config

```
pipelines:
 default:
- step:
    image: mysql:5.7
    script:
     - how to import sql file
     - how to set root password
- step:
    image: php:v1
    caches:
      - composer
    script:
      - composer install
      - ./init 0
      - ./vendor/bin/codecept build
      - ./vendor/bin/codecept run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm guessing you want to run tests with that mysql as a database? in that case you should configure the database server as a service (see https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/test-with-databases-in-bitbucket-pipelines-856697462.html), then you can configure env variables for the db-service.

if you really just want to set the env variable for your build container you will have to do so in the dockerfile itself or in the pipeline settings of your repository. env variables added there will be available in all steps of the pipeline (see https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/environment-variables-794502608.html).